Interpreting a Polish rental listing
I don't read Polish yet, but with auto-translation assistance, it seems that if my wife and I were to rent this tiny apartment, we would pay (złoty):
Rent     990
Util     240
Admin   1040

But "administrative fee"?  Is that a monthly fee allowing them to hide the true cost in fine print, or is it a one-time upfront commission, finder's fee, or some such?
And it says "two rooms" but it seems to have four: bedroom, living room, bathroom, kitchen.  Is it normal to not include kitchen and bathroom in the count?

Yes, it is normal that 'bathroom, kitchen' are not considered 'rooms' in this context.

Most likely a one off agency fee

@Traveller, thanks.  That article not only answers the second question, it alerts me to other terminology issues.  And perhaps when I finiwh reading it, I'll see the other answer.
